# Elgg with within subdirectory that is not executed by elgg

Tags: wordpress, elgg

I have website that run elgg in root directory. 
But I want into subdirectory that is located within elgg put wordpress site.

> Example:
>      www.mysite.com  - elgg,
>      www.mysite.com/wp  - wordpress
>
> Yes, and I don't need any kind of integration between them (no bridge)
>      Just to elgg not to execute this folder

So I need for directory www.mysite.com/wp different rules than for rest site.
I tried changing .htaccess file for www.mysite.com/wp directory, but I think it's wrong way.
It is working only for simple .php files, but wordpress is more complex and after long period of loading It show elgg "nothing found" site loaded.

Please don't ask change site structure, it is already set. And wordpress in subdirectory also has it's reasons.

I know there must be easy solution for this issue like elgg plugin for subdirectories, but problem is that web is flooded with topics about installing elgg in subdirectory and I can't find solution.

Comment: Ideally it should work. u have not mentioned what was the rule you have put in root .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rewrite rule that uses ^$ to represent the root and rewrite that to your /wp directory, and write  this just above index.php  like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp(.*)$ /wp [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?__elgg_uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```